# push() causes db._checkNotDeleted is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store an object in the database. Below is my code.

```
app.post('/newOrderWithObject', (req, res) => {

    var msg = {"name":"Harry"};
    push(ref(db,"test/orders"), msg);

    res.status(200).send(req.body);
})
```

I used `set()` many times in my code and everything worked but this code gave me the error and now nothing works, even though I have not touched any line other than this code. It seems this functions somehow manages to corrupt the whole working code but I don't know how. This also happened before and I had to recover my entire project from the GitHub.
This is the error:
`db._checkNotDeleted is not a function`.
Can anyone please point out my mistake here.

Comment: maybe a bad reference to db? can you inspect the db object?

Comment: @ThisGuy I used that same db object in many functions before and everything worked fine. Btw I don’t understand what you mean by inspecting db object.

Comment: Can you show how you import the functions and initialize things? Basically: a minimal-but-complete file that reproduces the error when we copy/paste/run it.

Comment: inspecting db object, https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/output-to-the-command-line-using-nodejs/ use console.log() or console.table() against your db object and even against the ._checkNotDeleted property.  "is not a function" could indicate that the db object is incorrect or not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was exporting my db object from another file with other objects like this:
`module.exports = {db, app};` and I changed it to only export db like this: `module.exports = db;` and it worked. I don't have much idea what was wrong with my previous code but now its working.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules